# Counter-example to the extended dominated convergence theorem

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

To add some context, let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space. The statement of the Extended Dominated Convergence Theorem(EDCT) is:

> $\lbrace f_{n}\rbrace_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of functions from $L^{1}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ such that $f_{n}\to f$ *a.e.($\mu$)* and there exists a sequence $\lbrace g_{n}\rbrace_{n\geq 1}\in L^{1}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ such that $g_{n}\to g$ *a.e.($\mu$)*, $|f_{n}|\leq g_{n}$ *a.e.($\mu$)* for all $n\geq 1$ and $\int g_{n}d\mu\to\int gd\mu$. Then, (i) $f\in L^{1}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ (ii) $f_{n}\xrightarrow{L^{1}} f$ (iii) $\int f_{n}d\mu \to \int fd\mu$

I'm stuck while trying to find a counterexample to the above theorem such that, $\lbrace f_{n}\rbrace_{n\geq 1}, f\in L^{1}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu), f_{n}\to f$ *a.e.($\mu$)* and $\int f_{n}d\mu\to\int f d\mu$ but $||f_{n}-f||_{L^{1}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)}\not\to 0$.

If the sequence of functions is non-negative, we can see $|f_{n}-f|\leq f_{n}+f=g_{n}$. Also, $\int g_{n}d\mu=\int f_{n}d\mu+\int fd\mu\to2\int fd\mu$. So applying the EDCT we cannot find a counter-example if the the sequence of functions is non-negative.

So is there any such example that shows that a sequence $g_{n}$ that dominates $f_{n}$ is necessary for convergence in $L^{1}$-norm. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: There are no hypotheses on $f$ or $g$. Given any sequence with $f_n\to f$ ae you could let $g_n=|f_n|$ and $g=|f|$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich under such assumption, to apply EDCT, we will additionally need $||f_{n}||_{L^{1}}\to||f||_{L^{1}}$. But $\int f_{n} d\mu\to\int fd\mu$ doesn't always imply $||f_{n}||_{L^{1}}\to||f||_{L^{1}}$. For example, consider the sequence of functions $f_{n}=nI_{(0,\frac{1}{n})}-nI_{(-\frac{1}{n},0)}$ and $f=0$ on the measure space $([-1,1],\mathcal{B}([-1,1]),m)$.

Comment: ??? No, we don't need to know $||f_n||\to||f||$ to apply EDCT as stated above! There's nothing about $||f_n||$ in the hypotheses.

Comment: In seems that something is missing in the Extended Dominated Convergence Theorem, you also need $\int g_n \rightarrow \int g$.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan Sorry, I missed that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counter-example:
Consider the measure space $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),m)$,
where $m$ is the usual Lebesgue measure. Let $f_{n}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
be defined by $f_{n}(x)=n^{2}1_{(\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{n})}(x)-n^{2}1_{(-\frac{1}{n},-\frac{1}{2n})}(x)$.
Define $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=0$. Clearly
$f_{n}\rightarrow f$ pointwisely. Moreover $\int f_{n}dm=\int dm=0$.
However $||f_{n}-f||_{1}\not\rightarrow0$.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

However, we have:

Let $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $(f_{n})$ be a
sequence of real-valued integrable functions defined on $X$. Let
$f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be an integrable function. Suppose that
$f_{n}\rightarrow f$ a.e., then $\lim_{n}\left(||f_{n}||-||f||-||f_{n}-f||\right)=0$,
where $||f||=\int|f|d\mu$ etc...

We go to prove the above assertion. Observe that $|f_{n}-f|\leq|f_{n}|+|f|$,
so $|f_{n}|-|f|-|f_{n}-f|\geq-2|f|.$ On the other hand, $|f_{n}|\leq|f_{n}-f|+|f|$
and hence $|f_{n}|-|f|-|f_{n}-f|\leq0\leq2|f|$. Combining, we have
$\Biggl||f_{n}|-|f|-|f_{n}-f|\Biggr|\leq2|f|$. Clearly, $|f_{n}|-|f|-|f_{n}-f|\rightarrow0$
a.e.. By Dominated Convergence Theorem, we have that $\int\left(|f_{n}|-|f|-|f_{n}-f|\right)d\mu\rightarrow 0$.
That is, $||f_{n}||-||f||-||f_{n}-f||\rightarrow0$.

Remark:

1. In particular, if $||f_n||\rightarrow ||f||$, then $||f_n-f||\rightarrow 0$
2. Counter-example does not exist if $f_n$ and $f$ are non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me whether you're saying EDCT is actually true; on the one hand your question says you're looking for a counterexample, but then the "such that" makes it unclear whether you're looking for a counterexample to EDCT.

In any case, EDCT (as stated above!) is clearly false. It has the following corollary:

> Assume EDCT. Suppose $\lbrace f_{n}\rbrace_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence of functions from $L^{1}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ such that $f_{n}\to f$ *a.e.($\mu$)*. Then, (i) $f\in L^{1}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ (ii) $f_{n}\xrightarrow{L^{1}} f$ (iii) $\int f_{n}d\mu \to \int fd\mu$.

You must know counterexamples to *that*. But

**Proof.** Let $g_n=|f_n|$, $g=|f|$. Then $g_n\in L^1$, $g_n\ge|f_n|$ and $g_n\to g$ almost everywhere. So EDCT implies (i), (ii) and (iii).

**Note** that if you add the hypothesis $\int g_n\to\int g\ge0$ then EDCT is a standard result (also true).